# Use HDMI if present, otherwise TRRS

Tags: hdmi, video, composite, rca

I sometimes use my Raspberry Pi OSMC install on an HDMI TV and sometimes on an older set with composite video phonos. there are many posts about disbling teh HMDI output. Having just read the definitions (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) of 
**hdmi_force_hotplug** and **hdmi_ignore_hotplug**, it looks like I can force video output either to TRRS (on the 2.5mm jack) or HDMI.

It is understood that the device should, by default output to HDMI, but revert to composite otherwise. Mine seems to need forced into using composite even when HDMI is absent.

I wonder: is it possible to send output to TRRS, unless HDMI is detected, in which case, HDMI should be used?

Thanks.

Comment: That's how the 3B+ and earlier Raspberries work. If the HDMI cable isn't connected it defaults to analog video. The RPi4B is different because of how the video timing is done on the ARM processor.

Comment: I'd hoped you were right. Mine seems to require to be forced to use composite if the HDMI is absent. (Question modified for clarity.) It must be something else in the OSMC config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having experimented with a virgin SD card install, I confirm Dougie's comment above: the default is HDMI, but if an HDMI monitor is absent, it falls back to using composite output.

I cannot yet explain why this doesn't seem to be the case for my OSMC installation. As such, the question is arguably in the wrong forum!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.